To perform OTA for BLE devices in Android Kotlin
When i write the end command after the data is written to the OTA data characteristics , the end command is found in the logs of the BLE device so the firmware is not updating.
I need to Perform OTA Firmware update for the BLE device. I am able to discover the services and characteristics , after discovery I need to write the .gbl to the OTA data characteristics . Before writing to the characteristics i am able to send the start command to the OTA control characterisitcs and once start command is written , the .gbl files is written the OTA data characteristics and once the data upload is finished ,i am also writing the end command to the OTA control characteristics but from the sensor side the firmware is not updated because the end command is found. THe expected is once the data is written and end command is passed the BLE devices disconnects from the gatt server.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
